# Spring | parameter with @value gets as value the label name and not the label value from .yaml file

Tags: spring

on spring micro-service project - having boolean parameter like this:

```
@Value("${a.b.c}")
private boolean flag;
```

on .yaml file having:

```
 a 
  b
   c: true
```

but while running the application getting :
*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${a.b.c}]
at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor.setAsText(CustomBooleanEditor.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429)*

while debugging looks like the parameter is getting the label name (*a.b.c*) and not the label value (*true*) and thats why fails on *invalid boolean* etc.

any idea whats wrong? what should be checked ? or fixed?

Comment: Are you using spring or spring boot? How do you add the yaml configuration file?

Comment: using spring boot, I am new to spring boot and doing some practice as part of training on existing project - .yaml is already configrued... not sure how - can u mention what should b checked?

Answer (score 1):

First off, your yaml looks wrong:

It should be (with colons):

```
a:
  b:
   c: true
```

Other than that, have you put these definitions into `application.yaml` (or yml) or you have some custom configuration?
If you put it into `application.yaml` the `@Value` itself is defined good in Java, so given the fact that the class that has this annotation on one of its field is by itself a spring bean, it should work.

Comment: sorry my mis.. It exists with colons but not in application.yaml file, looks like this project has some custom configuration .. this def. is inside .yaml file with diff name under project1\src\main\resources\<custom-name>.yaml and the class with the @value is under project2\src\main\java\<class-using-def>.java. for teammate it works with same code ,not sure whats wrong any idea?

Comment: Are both project1 and project2 spring boot applications? How does project2 "knows" that it can read the configuration of project1? In general this setup can be much more complicated in this case

Comment: looks like issue solved by entering few spaces inside the .yaml file next to a.b.c. def. , I guess spring could not read the structure of a.b.c since those missing spaces and now its fine, any way thanks for help